# Prerequisitions for Team Foundation Service 2015 and SSDT

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015, team-foundation-server

We have installed the new TFS 2015 in our company and now i'm trying to make a successful CI build.

At the moment the build always fails with this message:

> The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Okay, it seems that the SSDT package is missing on the Build Server.

What i have found is, that you need to install a Visual Studio (2015?) on the maching where the agents are.

See here: [Want a headless build server for SSDT without installing Visual Studio? You’re out of luck!](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2014/08/08/want-a-headless-build-server-for-ssdt-without-installing-visual-studio-you-re-out-of-luck.aspx)

As far as i understand this, we need to install at least a VS 2015 Community Edition on the BuildServer to get SSDT packages compile successfully?

Questions:

- Is the Community Edition sufficient for this?
- When no, which licence should we use for a Professional edition or do we just need to install it and never fire it up?
- Is there a solution other than installing Visual Studio? (Maybe i didn't found it till now)

Hopefully someone has a bit of experience with this.